# CyanogenMod 11 nightly on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 (gt-p5100)

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery

I'm getting the `set_metadata_recursive: some changes failed` problem. All over the internet, it says to upgrade CWM to 6.0.4.5 or higher, but I'm using the latest for this device (6.0.2.7) according to the site, how do I get a later version? Or if I can't, how else can I get the latest CyanogenMod on the tablet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get it going by using [TWRP](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2) instead of CWM. TWRP is much better!